# UIAlertView клавиатура не появляется

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, swift

Создал *UIAlertView* с двумя текстовыми полями.

Столкнулся с проблемой с симуляторами *IOS 8.4* на *IPhone 6* и *IPad Air* (на остальных устройствах работает нормально):

При нажатии на любое из текстовых полей — не выдвигается клавиатура.

Находил решения в сети, но ни одно не подошло.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте в iOS Simulator > Hardware > Keyboard - убрать галочки.

Comment: Большое спасибо. Сделал, теперь все работает